# Execute a formula in mysql for millions of data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have table `users` which has millions of data

`users` have colums like id, competed_date, thirdparty_id etc etc

`thirdparty_id` is new column i have to update for all users

proces to find thirdparty_id

for each user there is corresponding order table from which we have to fetch latest order
from which we will get one value based on it we can calculate some rate

that rate we can search in another table thirdpary from there we will get  `thirdparty_id`

i have did everything for individual users its working fine

now my question is how to execute this for millions of users?

i am using laravel

the process is fetch all  users having thirdparty_id null
and call formula function to find id and update

but fetch all means millions of data in single query?
so if i am giving limit whats maximum limit i can give?

what are another options to execute?

queries i used

```
select id as userid from users where thirdparty_id is null limit {some limit}

in foreach of this

select amount from orders wehere user_id =userid order by created desc limit 1

some wiered formula with amount will give `rate`

select id from third party where start_rate > rate and end_rate<rate

update users set thirdparty_id=id where id=userid
```

Comment: Please add the query you used for 1 record, the explanation is not easy to understand.

Comment: If it's a query you'll only run once, i'd advise using SQL on the database directly. Using an ORM is going to be excruciatingly slow if you have to update millions of records.

Answer (score 1):

You can use chunk: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-results

something like this:

```
public const CHUNK_SIZE = 5000;

...

User::whereNull('thirdparty_id')->chunk(self::CHUNK_SIZE, function (Collection $users) {
    // $users is collection contains 5000 users, you can do mass update them or something you want  
});
```

Comment: If you don't wanna use stored procedures, for example because you are more familiar with php or wanna control it via Laravel, I'd make a Laravel Command and then, as described^^, do whereNull and chunk. Like this you can use multiple workers, or even cron job, to execute the command as suites your needs.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of problematic, I will use a stored procedure to do the update instead of using language like PHP.

Doing this the migration stored procedure run inside MySQL Server and you throw away all problems like PHP execution time, memory limits, Apache timeout, etc.